# How to get plain text of https package locally?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

How to get plain text of a https package sent from my program? There is a tcpdump on my system. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use tshark, a wireshark-like commandline tool.

Example usage (with parameters that fit MY system) :

```
tshark -i eth1 port 443 -o "ssl.keys_list:any,443,http,/path/to/your/server.key" -o ssl.debug_file:"/home/your_user/ssl_debug.log"
```

Of course, replace "eth1" with your interface.
The ssl_debug.log is "just in case".

You can parse more of the data (headers,..) [like this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/16964/analyzing-http-protocol-using-tshark)

[tshark documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

Comment: damn unfortunately I don't have access to the server's private key

Answer (score 3):

Because any traffic over HTTPS is encrypted, it is not possible to sniff the plaintext using tcpdump.

You can do a [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack on your HTTPS stream (using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp), for example). However, this will give certificate errors on your client.

Comment: Because tcpdump and the program are on the same os, I think there must be a way to capture the package before it's be encrypted by https, isn't it?

Comment: If you mean the TCP packet by "the package", then no. The TCP packet is not filled and then encrypted, it is filled with encrypted data. So you can not ever see the content on the TCP level. You can attach a debugger to your program, or change the program to write the stream to a file, to read the contents before they are sent over the SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) has some capabilities to decrypt SSL/TLS traffic; see [the SSL page in the Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) for informaton on this.  Of course, you will need some information from your machine in order to do it (if you could decrypt *arbitrary* SSL/TLS traffic, SSL/TLS wouldn't be very useful...).  You could either capture the traffic with tcpdump (make sure you capture with `-w`, so that the trace is saved in pcap format, and with `-s 0` so that you capture *all* the data in the packet) or with Wireshark.